# I want to add an object to the react array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to add an object to the state array.
I want to add an object {user.uuid,user.id} to the state array using the spread syntax,
I want to add an object {user.uuid,user.id} to the state array. But I get an error and can't add any value to the state.
If anyone knows how to solve this problem, please let me know.

```
  const [id, setId] = React.useState<[{uuid: number; id: number}]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id === null) {
     users.map((user) => setId([...id, {user.uuid, user.id}]));
    }
  }, [users]);
```

I would like to create such an array.

```
[
  { uuid:sadsa
    id:1
  },
  { uuid:dadsad
    id:2
  },
  { uuid:jihji
    id:3
  },
  { uuid:mokok
    id:4
  },
]
```

Comment: Please, always show the actual error you're getting. Also, the array of objects that you're showing is looking suspicious. Unless the values of uuids are variables, you have to use quotes around them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding from your code is that your state is an array, which means that the type you want to use is `{uuid: number; id: number}[]`. Thus, the `useState` statement should be:

```
const [id, setId] = React.useState<{uuid: number; id: number}[]>([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// define Item type
type Item = {
    uuid: number, id: number
}

// define type as Item array
const [id, setId] = React.useState<Item[] | []>([]);

const user: Item = { uuid: 1, id: 123 };

// setId accepts array of Item, So
setId([...id, user]);
```